# Does the query still run even when SQL Server can't grant the requested memory for the query?

Tags: sql-server, memory, memory-grant

I was thinking about something like this today but I couldn't find this piece of information.

When the SQL Server requests memory and the OS can't provide it, we get a `RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE` wait type.

but I can't find info like:

1. lets say the query asks for 3GB. But it's only possible to provide 2, does the query still run slowly, or it keeps there waiting?
2. `RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE` means the query is in a "stopped" state just waiting for the memory?
3. Memory grants pending should always be on 0 right? this means how much memory the queries are requesting but still waiting right?

I was reading [Memory Grants: The mysterious SQL Server memory consumer with Many Names](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support-blog/memory-grants-the-mysterious-sql-server-memory-consumer-with/ba-p/333994) from Microsoft, but it doesn't explain this, it just explains what a Memory grant is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Paul Randal describes the [RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/resource_semaphore/):

> This wait type is when a thread is waiting for a query execution
> memory grant so it **can begin** executing. [emphasis added]

I understand without the needed memory the query **cannot begin**. His article also mentions the query wont wait for ever:

> High waits of this type are because queries cannot get the memory they
> need to execute, and you may also see error 8645 (“A timeout occurred
> while waiting for memory resources to execute the query in resource
> pool ‘’ (). Rerun the query.”

The doc [How to troubleshoot SQL Server error 8645](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-troubleshoot-sql-server-error-8645-a1bbec30-e71e-08f7-bc35-0e3bc34bed76) might also help:

> The error message 8645 is raised when memory-intensive queries, such
> as those involving sorting and hashing, are queued and are unable to
> obtain the requested memory before a time-out period. SQL Server waits
> for memory for a length of time that is based on the query wait
> configuration value. By default, the query wait value is set to -1,
> which means SQL Server waits for 25 times the estimated cost of the
> query. If you modify the query wait value to a non-negative number,
> SQL Server waits for the number of seconds that you specify in the
> value of the query wait option.